# Why can I store objects in array that differ in size?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-address

for example the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class VectorContainer
{
public:
  VectorContainer(std::vector<int>::size_type sz)
  {
    foo.reserve(sz);
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        foo.push_back(i);
    }
  }

  std::vector<int> foo;
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

  VectorContainer containerOne(0);

  VectorContainer containerTwo(1);

  std::cout << &containerOne << std::endl;

  std::cout << &containerTwo << std::endl;

  VectorContainer arr[2] = {containerOne, containerTwo};

  std::cout << &arr[0] << std::endl;

  std::cout << &arr[1] << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

produces following output:

```
0x7ffeefbff578
0x7ffeefbff560
0x7ffeefbff5e0
0x7ffeefbff5f8
```

Why is it here possible to store VectorContainers (that differ in size) in one array without any negative effects? And why are the last two addresses differ from the first both ones?

I would have thought that containerOne and containerTwo lie directly in the array container without any pointer.

Comment: you can also write `std::vector<int> foo[2]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is it here possible to store VectorContainers (that differ in size) in one array without any negative effects?

Because every `VectorContainer` object has the same *object representation* taking the same amount of bytes `sizeof(VectorContainer)`, which is essentially `sizeof(std::vector<>)`. The key is that a vector itself holds a *pointer* to a different region of memory that actually can vary in size. But as the size of this region has no influence on the size of the pointer (and thus on the representation layout of the vector object), you can pack those objects into a common array.

Note that this technique is basically the heart of polymorphism as well.

> And why are the last two addresses differ from the first both ones?

Because they relate to completely distinct objects. The first two are separate objects while the last two are part of an array that got copied from the first ones when you initialized the array.

Comment: ok sure, when std::vector holds under the hood an pointer to an array where my integers are saved, then it is clear.

Comment: you mean that the encapsulation via pointers is the heart of polymorphism ?

Comment: @MagicMaik Objects of different derived classes may have different sizes, but you can put base class pointers of them into an array. By taking pointers, you give different objects an equal object representation. `std::vector` is doing nothing different in the sense of managing memory regions of different sizes using a pointer.
Note that if you take `std::array` for your example, it will fail to compile, as array holds no pointer and the storage is directly part of the object representation, hence it's part of the type.

Comment: @MagicMaik: This answer says nothing about polymorphism, and in fact `std::vector` doesn't handle polymorphism (A `std::vector<Base>` can't hold `Derived` objects). Yes, a pointer to a _single_ derived class object can be converted to a base class subobject, but that doesn't work with arrays.

Comment: I dont see the point with polymorphism. the example you explained, @Jodocus, works, because when you pass a subclass object to a base class argument, the pointer is implicitly casted. but that cast does nothing. because in memory, the base class objects lies before the subclass object. so the pointer still points to the same address. The subclass object and the base class object are just nested.

Comment: @MagicMaik Yes. But if you call a *virtual* method on these pointers, you work with very different objects that may vary in size as well. You can do this because you got a common interface by the pointer indirection. This is the very essence of my point.

Comment: @Jodocus, Mhh I would not agree with that so easily. If you have virtual functions, your objects have a field with a pointer to a vtable. and the vtable says which function implementation to call. I really dont see what this has to do with different sizes of objects. but I think we are a little bit off topic.

Comment: @MagicMaik Yes, a *pointer* to a vtable again. Pointers are the mean to give different objects of related types equivalent object representations.